# Kendoui Angular2 install 404s with Angular 2 Seed

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, systemjs, kendo-ui-angular2, angular2-seed

I am using [Angular 2 See](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed#configuration)d app and trying to install KendoUI Angular2 controls.

The seed uses SystemJS but is generated on `npm start`. I have tried to add external dependency using from [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency) but I cannot get it to work.

I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:47 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs.js(…) "Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues"
```

Here is what I have tried adding to `/tools/config/project.config.ts`

```
    this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['@progress/kendo-angular-inputs'] =
        `node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs`;

    this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['@progress/kendo-angular-inputs'] = {
      main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    };
```

Comment: Any solutions?  I have having a similar problem.  I've tried all of the prescribed solutions. 1) the installation (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#installation), 2) the plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview), 3) and even the github site (https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard/issues/16)

Comment: I have not been able to solve it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pathing was a little off. This fixed it

```
this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['@progress/kendo-angular-dialog'] =
        `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dialog/dist/npm/js/main`;

    this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['@progress/kendo-angular-dialog'] = {
      main: '/dist/npm/js/main',
      defaultExtension : 'js'
    };
```

and you need to add the style ref to your index.html. I could not get it to work in the config file or in the component file.